# The cumulative calculation is not being done properly when the number is negative

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

| final_date | final_precise_date | local_limit_amount | limit_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/10/2020 | 2020-12-10 18:45:10.590 | 1000000.000000 | 4800000.00 |
| 12/10/2020 | 2020-12-10 18:45:37.650 | 800000.000000 | 4800000.00 |
| 12/18/2020 | 2020-12-18 19:01:09.530 | 1425000.000000 | 4800000.00 |
| 12/31/2020 | 2020-12-31 00:00:00.000 | -1425000.000000 | 4800000.00 |
| 01/18/2021 | 2021-01-18 00:00:00.000 | 500000.000000 | 4800000.00 |
| 04/27/2021 | 2021-04-27 00:00:00.000 | -800000.000000 | 4800000.00 |
| 07/22/2021 | 2021-07-22 00:00:00.000 | -1000000.000000 | 4800000.00 |
| 12/31/2021 | 2021-12-31 00:00:00.000 | -500000.000000 | 4800000.00 |

The local_limit_amount should be increasing or decreasing cumulatively from a line to another.

I have written the following code in order to fetch data cumulatively:

```sql
SELECT
    final_date            AS 'value_date'
    , final_precise_date  AS 'precise_value_date'
    , limit_amount
    , limit_amount_ccy_id
    , (
        LAG(local_limit_amount, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY final_precise_date) 
        + LAG(local_limit_amount, 2, 0) OVER (ORDER BY final_precise_date) 
        + local_limit_amount
      )                   AS 'local_limit_amount'
    , future_exposure     AS 'initial_exposure'
    , future_availability AS 'initial_availability'
FROM
    #temp3
ORDER BY
    final_precise_date ASC
```

However the calculation is only correct for the first 3 lines since the amount to be incremented is positive, starting from the fourth line, all of the cumulation becomes wrong since the amount should be 1800000 while I am only seeing 800000

| value_date | precise_value_date | limit_amount | limit_amount_ccy_id | local_limit_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/10/2020 | 2020-12-10 18:45:10.590 | 4800000.00 | 22 | 1000000.000000 |
| 12/10/2020 | 2020-12-10 18:45:37.650 | 4800000.00 | 22 | 1800000.000000 |
| 12/18/2020 | 2020-12-18 19:01:09.530 | 4800000.00 | 22 | 3225000.000000 |
| 12/31/2020 | 2020-12-31 00:00:00.000 | 4800000.00 | 22 | 800000.000000 |
| 01/18/2021 | 2021-01-18 00:00:00.000 | 4800000.00 | 22 | 500000.000000 |
| 04/27/2021 | 2021-04-27 00:00:00.000 | 4800000.00 | 22 | -1725000.000000 |
| 07/22/2021 | 2021-07-22 00:00:00.000 | 4800000.00 | 22 | -1300000.000000 |
| 12/31/2021 | 2021-12-31 00:00:00.000 | 4800000.00 | 22 | -2300000.000000 |

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I followed you correctly  you need `sum` amalytical function.

Replace

```
(
 LAG(local_limit_amount, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY final_precise_date) 
 + LAG(local_limit_amount, 2, 0) OVER (ORDER BY final_precise_date) 
 + local_limit_amount
)
```

With

```
Sum(local_limit_amount) OVER (ORDER BY final_precise_date)
```